# Matlab switch-case issue

Tags: matlab, user-interface, switch-statement, case

I got a strange issue when i try to run a multiple switch-case ( 6 concatened switch-case, from 2 to 11 choices, char choices).
the inputs for the m. file with the swith case come from a GUI with 6 buttongroup and radiobutton, but i guess this is not the problem.
In fact, the problem is that if i pass the values "manually", kinda:

```
evaluation= Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree('midv','rn','fd', 'oop', 'hu',25)
```

i got to the right solution, that is simply a string ( ideally, this will return to the GUI and will be replace in an EDIT-TEXT box):

```
evaluation =

bettiamo perchè oop e calla abb spesso per floatare.                                                   
 Al turn decidiamo di c/c o c/r su blank in base alla size, se cade suited c/f.                        
 se turn abbiamo c/c e river è blank siamo in modalità vita c/c bottom-mid case:          cbetptkiamo perchè oop.
 Se raisa foldiamo.
```

Instead, if i do

```
evaluation= Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree(handles.val, handles.act, handles.text, handles.pos, handles.num, handles.bb);
```

and

```
handles.val='midv';
handles.act='rn';
handles.text='fd';
handles.pos='oop';
handles.num='hu';
handles.bb=25;
```

i get this error

```
??? Undefined function or variable "evaluation".

Error in ==> Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree at 6998
```

Moreover, if i create a Main.m like so:

```
value= input (' Value', 's');
action=input(' Action: ','s');
texture= input (' Texture', 's');
pos=input(' Position: ','s');
num= input (' Opponumber', 's');
bb=input(' Big blinds: ');
evaluation= Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree(value, action, texture, pos, num,bb);
```

it does work!
I really dont get it: what's the difference? I checked that all handles.field are char, and if not, i've placed at the very beginning this:

```
value=char(value);
actionpre=char(actionpre);
texture=char(texture);
pos=char(pos);
opponumber=char(opponumber);
```

I thought it was a multiple switch case problem, because if i enter the Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree.m from the GUI and i make separate switch-case, Matlab runs it, while it stops at the third, but now i cant think it's a multiple s-c problem, since if i put the value manually it goes through it without problem.
Any help?

P.S: i'll add the code for the string above:

```
case 'midv'
    switch actionpre
        case 'rn' 
            switch texture
                case 'fd'
                    switch pos
                        case 'ip'
                            switch opponumber
                                case 'hu' 
                                   evaluation=' No info yet.';
                                case 'multiway' 
                                   evaluation=' No info yet.';
                            end
                        case 'oop'
                             switch opponumber
                                case 'hu' 
                                    if bb>15
                                       evaluation='Cbettiamo perchè oop e calla abb spesso per floatare. Al turn decidiamo di c/c o c/r su blank in base alla size, se cade suited c/f.se turn abbiamo c/c e river è blank siamo in modalità vita c/c bottom-mid case: cbetptkiamo perchè oop. Se raisa foldiamo. Al turn se non improviamo siamo sempre in c/f a meno di info che non foldi spesso alla 2barrel, in quel caso possiamo betptkare, se calla e non improviamo river o turn è suited siamo in c/f river';
                                    else
                                        evaluation='cbettiamo per brokare';
                                    end
                                case 'multiway' 
                                   evaluation=' No info yet.';
                             end
```

Comment: Can you please add the entire code for the `Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree` function? Its hard to tell what's going on otherwise. For instance, in the code you posted you have a case without a corresponding switch statement

Comment: Also, based on your error, it seems you're trying to use the variable `evaluation` before you set it. Is `evaluation` anywhere on the right side of an equals sign?

Comment: I cannot post the entire code, it's about 7000 lines since it's 5 switch-case with the external one, the bigger, with 11 choices, then 6, 6, 2, 2 and a final if. The starting line is:
    function eval= Holdem_Postflop_Decision_Tree(value, actionpre, texture, pos, opponumber,bb)        

while the missing switch is simply switch value.
The error is kinda logic for matlab: at the end of the code i split evaluation string in lines separated by the dot, and it gives an error since it nevers goes through the final if of the example even if all the values bring to it.

Comment: How do you know "it nevers goes through the final if of the example even if all the values bring to it". Did you try using the debugger/breakpoints?

Comment: Yeah, sure i did it, and that's why i'm astonished that it does work when i enter the values manually ( debugging it, it goes through all the right cases), while when i pass the values from the GUI it stops after a switch or two, randomly, and the "evaluation" string is never defined and it gives that error.
Moreover, what's more surprising, it's that if i debug after the GUI  input and before any switch operation, and i give the inputs manually, it works; then i continue the debug and i get the error, but the values i pass to the function are the same, same strings!

Comment: Solved, i guess. The problem was this:
handles.act='rn';

there's a space before the last comma, removing it makes it all work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :-)

Comment: Now i have to understand why if i debug the code and run it it takes about 2 seconds to get to the ending, while if i close and open Matlab and run it by scratch or without debugging the first execution takes over a minute.

Comment: Who on earth creates such a switch monster? I'd assume the timing behaviour you observe simply arises from the fact that matlab is internally loading/compiling (whatever you may call it) the function  upon the first call. Once loaded, it's fast - upon change or matlab restart it will of course have to be rebuilt.